# AttributeError python how i solve

Tags: python

**Hi i have this code with python which choose three column(Time", "Node", "DelayS), with condition among the conditions in the Type column choose just "LastDelay" when I executed i have this problem "
***AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Type'"***" How I can solve this problem???? I tried many solutions but it doesn't work
And thank you in advance  **

```
import pandas
import csv
import pandas as pd


file = 'delayintersection.txt'

table = pandas.read_csv(file, delimiter='\t')

table2 = table[(table.Type == "LastDelay")]
table29 = table2[["Time", "Node", "DelayS"]]
table29.to_csv("./delay.csv", index=False)

############################# Node 29##############################

file = open('delay.csv')
csvreader = csv.reader(file)
rows = []
for row in csvreader:
    if ("29" in row):
        rows.append(row)

# name of csv file
filename = "finalresultsdelay29.csv"
# field names
fields = ['Time', 'Node', 'DelayS']
# writing to csv file
with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
    # creating a csv writer object
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)

    # writing the fields
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)

    # writing the data rows
    csvwriter.writerows(rows)

df = pd.read_csv("finalresultsdelay29.csv")
# checking the number of empty rows in th csv file
print(df.isnull().sum())
# Droping the empty rows
modifiedDF = df.dropna()
modifiedDF.to_csv('finalresultsdelay29.csv', index=False)

############################# Node 39##############################
file = open('delay.csv')
csvreader = csv.reader(file)
rows = []
for row in csvreader:
    if ("39" in row):
        rows.append(row)

# name of csv file
filename = "finalresultsdelay39.csv"
# field names
fields = ['Time', 'Node', 'DelayS']
# writing to csv file
with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
    # creating a csv writer object
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)

    # writing the fields
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)

    # writing the data rows
    csvwriter.writerows(rows)

df = pd.read_csv("finalresultsdelay39.csv")
# checking the number of empty rows in th csv file
print(df.isnull().sum())
# Droping the empty rows
modifiedDF = df.dropna()
modifiedDF.to_csv('finalresultsdelay39.csv', index=False)
#############################Node 84 #################################
file = open('delay.csv')
csvreader = csv.reader(file)
rows = []
for row in csvreader:
    if ("84" in row):
        rows.append(row)

# name of csv file
filename = "finalresultsdelay84.csv"
# field names
fields = ['Time', 'Node', 'DelayS']
# writing to csv file
with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
    # creating a csv writer object
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)

    # writing the fields
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)

    # writing the data rows
    csvwriter.writerows(rows)

df = pd.read_csv("finalresultsdelay84.csv")
# checking the number of empty rows in th csv file
print(df.isnull().sum())
# Droping the empty rows
modifiedDF = df.dropna()
modifiedDF.to_csv('finalresultsdelay84.csv', index=False)
```

[image: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Type']

Comment: Posting images of code isn't very useful. Copying and pasting both the code and the error message would help get you answers.

Comment: Check [ask]. Don't post images of code, error, data, etc. Copy/paste as formatted text. Also - show what have you tried and how it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing it out like `table['Type']` instead.

Comment: I tried free but it didn't work